# Is sockjs relevant to Android/iOS apps?

Tags: javascript, websocket, sockjs

I want to create a chat app and get bought for $19B. From the sockjs web page it says:

> "SockJS is intended to work for all modern browsers and in environments which don't support WebSocket protocol, for example behind restrictive corporate proxies."

If I run my chat server on port 80 at a dedicated subdomain, wouldn't that mean people could still use it even behind "restrictive corporate proxies"? In what scenarios would sockjs be useful for a mobile app compared to just using native web sockets?

FYI the app will be a phonegap app, and the chat server will be based on tornado.